# UIView+Category access dealloc or do something on UIView dealloc call

Tags: ios, iphone, uikit

How to trigger an action in a Class Category when the object gets deallocated without subclassing and overriding the dealloc method. I'm trying to implement a category on `UIView`.

Comment: The aim was to build this https://github.com/nicpro85/UIView-Gravity

Comment: I found it clear enough

Answer (score 2, accepted):

swizzle dealloc. it is evil but we do it too :D

in +load of your category swizzle dealloc and you're in

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <objc/runtime.h>

@interface T : NSObject
@end

@interface T (myCat)
@end

@implementation T
- (void)dealloc {
    NSLog(@"2");
}
@end

@implementation T (myCat)
+ (void)load {
    SEL originalSelector = @selector(NSSelectorFromString(dealloc));
    SEL overrideSelector = @selector(xchg_dealloc);
    Method originalMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(self, originalSelector);
    Method overrideMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(self, overrideSelector);
    if (class_addMethod(self, originalSelector, method_getImplementation(overrideMethod), method_getTypeEncoding(overrideMethod))) {
        class_replaceMethod(self, overrideSelector, method_getImplementation(originalMethod), method_getTypeEncoding(originalMethod));
    } else {
        method_exchangeImplementations(originalMethod, overrideMethod);
    }
}
- (void)xchg_dealloc {
    NSLog(@"1");
    [self xchg_dealloc]; //calls original
}
@end
```

Comment: untested, written in editor -- but the principle is sound

Comment: works fine for any objc runtime (iOS / osx)

Comment: Okay I try it and mark it accordingly thank for the idea, seems pretty evil indeed :)

Comment: there is also a slightly less evil way.. using a helper object

Comment: code for which I also added.

Comment: thanks i'm guessing parent is super here right?

Comment: looks like ARC forbid use of dealloc in @selector()

Comment: thats what NSSelectorFromString is for

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45914/discussion-between-nicolas-manzini-and-daij-djan)

Comment: we use it with arc since forever

Comment: Whenever i end the swizzled "dealloc" with a call to self (to "call original"), it prints logs in expected order but then crashes with error:
-[MyClass release]:message sent to deallocated instance

Comment: well then there is limey something else in your code Im afraid: this don't send additional releases

Answer (score 1):

IF you don't like swizzling there is a maybe less evil but more fragile & convoluted way

you use a Helper object that gets deallocated by the runtime as some sort of marker

```
@interface T_Helper : NSObject
@public
__weak T *parent;
@end
@implementation T_Helper
- (void)dealloc {
    [parent my_dealloc];
}
@end

@implementation T (myCat)
- (void)doSomethingThatLaterWantsDealloc {
    T_Helper *helper = [T_Helper alloc] init];
    helper->parent = self;
    objc_setAssociatedObject(self, "helper", helper, OBJ_ASSOSIATION_RETAIN);
}
- (void)my_dealloc {
    NSLog(@"1");
}
@end
```

Comment: code based on my other answer